# C# OpenXML 2.5. I want to replace a merge field with an image

Tags: c#, openxml, mergefield

I have a requirement to insert a mergefield say << MERGEFIELD Image >> and replace it with the actual image. I know how to loop through FieldCodes and when the field name matches with the merge field name, replace it with a TEXT value. But my requirement is to Give the users option to use a Mail merge field on the document, but then I need to replace the mail merge field with an image. Can anyone help on this with a working example.

Comment: post some code, show what effort you've made and let us help you with a specific issue you're having

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to know what approach you're taking for "replacing" the merge fields. So we can't give you a meaningful answer. It actually shouldn't be any different, basically, than what you already have except you're inserting a picture instead of text. You also have to know where to get the picture? What the file name is?